# How to resize product bundle thumbnail on Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

Can someone provide information on how to change the thumbnail resolution for Magento bundle products? I've attempted the following code on my view.xml file:

```
<image id="bundle_page_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
<width>150</width>
<height>150</height>
</image>
<image id="bundle_page_product_image" type="image">
<width>500</width>
<height>500</height>
</image>
```

and this is my whole view.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
<image id="bundle_page_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
<width>150</width>
<height>150</height>
</image>
<image id="bundle_page_product_image" type="image">
<width>500</width>
<height>500</height>
</image>

        <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
            <width>34</width>
            <height>34</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
            <width>34</width>
            <height>34</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>

        <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid_big" type="small_image">
            <width>528</width>
            <height>528</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list_small" type="small_image">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list_group" type="small_image">
            <width>130</width>
            <height>130</height>
        </image>
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>109</width>
            <height>109</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
        <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>535</width>
            <height>535</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
            <width>118</width>
            <height>118</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_swatch_image_large" type="image"/>
        <image id="product_swatch_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_swatch_image_small" type="thumbnail">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>110</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>535</width>
            <height>535</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>535</width>
            <height>535</height>
        </image>
        <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>264</width>
            <height>264</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="thumbmargin">20</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails margin set -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview in fullscreen (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title in fullscreen(true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in fullscreen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="navarrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>

    <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
    </var>

    <var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">768px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="nav">dots</var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
    <!-- end. Gallery and magnifier theme settings -->

    <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

    <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
    <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>           <!-- New Product image size used for zooming -->

    <var name="product_image_white_borders">1</var>
</vars>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

thank you in advance